# How to compute population density of certain type with Arcmap table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have to find areas on a map where the yearly income is less than a certain threshold, I have all of the data laid out in a table but I am not sure how to process it.

The density for a statistical area can be defined as the ratio of:
 - (the number people who earn less than x in area1) / (the area of the
   area1 (in hectare))

Statistical areas are classified as ‘high density’ if they have a density greater than 3 people who earn x or less per hectare.

table is laid out like this: $x to $y amount = 20 people, for example. (so they have all been categorised already)

I have worked out how to create a list of the density by simply doing the division above, but how would I classify these numbers into < 3?

Also, how would I go about ignoring, or not displaying the areas that do not suit my needs (eg. > 3)

Answer (score 3):

Use Select by Attribute.  Fill in the expression field using the buttons and choices shown in the boxes, so that it says something like "density" < 3.  You will get a subset of the original data where all of the densities are less than 3.  If that's all you need, right-click on the result in the table of contents, go to Selection, and choose "create layer from selected features."